# webdriver implicitWait not working as expected

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In webdriver code if i use `thread.sleep(20000)`. It's waiting for 20 seconds, and my code also works fine. 
To archive the same if i use implicit wait like

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

It's not waiting forcefully for 20 seconds and goes to next steps just in 3 to 4 seconds. and page still loading.

This is wired situation as i am using fluent wait to find some elements. if the elements still loading on the page it does not show error and make the test passed.

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
  .withTimeout(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
  public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
    return driver.findElement(By.id("jxxx"));
  }
});
```

But if i say wrong id it waits for 50 seconds but other test got passed without clicking.. it is not showing any error.

My Question is how I should avoid `Thread.sleep()` as other selenium methods are not helping me..

Comment: thanks for looking into this @JimEvans, I have edited my code and now using only fluent wait, but its not givng any error and not doing anything as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below method to wait for a element:

```
public boolean waitForElementToBePresent(By by, int waitInMilliSeconds) throws Exception
{

    int wait = waitInMilliSeconds;
    int iterations  = (wait/250);
    long startmilliSec = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        if((System.currentTimeMillis()-startmilliSec)>wait)
            return false;
        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(by);
        if (elements != null && elements.size() > 0)
            return true;
        Thread.sleep(250);
    }
    return false;
}
```

And below method is to wait for page load:

```
public void waitForPageLoadingToComplete() throws Exception {
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectation = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
                    "return      document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }
    };
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(expectation);
}
```

Let's assume you are waiting for a page to load. Then call the 1st method with waiting time and any element which appears after page loading then it will return `true`, other wise `false`. Use it like,

```
waitForElementToBePresent(By.id("Something"), 20000)
```

The above called function waits until it finds the given element within given duration.

Try any of below code after above method

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id<locator>));
```

or

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id<locator>));
```

Update:

```
public boolean waitForTextFiled(By by, int waitInMilliSeconds, WebDriver wdriver) throws Exception
    {
        WebDriver driver = wdriver;
        int wait = waitInMilliSeconds;
        int iterations  = (wait/250);
        long startmilliSec = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            if((System.currentTimeMillis()-startmilliSec)>wait)
                return false;
            driver.findElement(By.id("txt")).sendKeys("Something");
            String name =  driver.findElement(by).getAttribute("value");

            if (name != null && !name.equals("")){
                return true;
            }
            Thread.sleep(250);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This will try entering text in to the text field till given time in millis. If `getAttribute()` is not suitable in your case use `getText()`. If text is enetered then it returns true. Put maximum time that u can wait until.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but the issue is if the page is still in loading condition, I don’t know how driver finds all the locators. and make the test pass. But actually it does not enter or click any elements. But if i put Thread.sleep it waits and fill and click the elements.

page loads perfectly only I put thread.sleep() 

Comment: driver finds the locator when the respective elements are visible only. You have to wait until a page loaded successfully and completely. Then only all elements are visible and can be identified by driver with proper element locators. see my edit.

Comment: I used the code. And its waiting for element to present, But only and only if i put thread.sleep() its writing text in the input box( in that element). as element is alraedy loaded why is not writing???              waitForElementToBePresent(By.id("txt"), 20000);driver.manage().window().maximize(); Thread.sleep(10000); driver.findElement(By.id("txt")).sendKeys("text");

Comment: just want to add the driver.manage.implicitWait(....) is also not working only thread.sleep is helping me to write in.. Pls help :)

Comment: Now I understand that your element is identified by the waitForElementToBePresent(By.id("txt"), 20000); method but the thing is that when element is identified the text box is still not editable. it's in disabled mode. After few seconds it's getting enabled. Do one thing, after this method check whether is editable or not. if not editable then u have to wait it to be editable

Comment: Thanks for understanding my pain. let me use isEnable,  will tell u the update, tnx

Comment: public static boolean waitForElementToEnable(String locator, int waitInMilliSeconds) throws Exception{int wait = waitInMilliSeconds;
int iterations  = (wait/250);long startmilliSec = System.currentTimeMillis();for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
 {if((System.currentTimeMillis()-startmilliSec)>wait)return false;
boolean enable = driver.findElement(By.id(locator)).isEnabled();
if (enable)return true;
Thread.sleep(200); } return false; }   have edited ur code to check enable, But no luck

Comment: Don't go for isEnabled. You should check whether the text box is clickable. For ex: when u want to enter some text manually in to ur text field u first click in the text field and enter string. So my suggestion is put wait condition for clickable as i suggested

Comment: Bro- I have used---   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("txt")));driver.findElement(By.id("txt")).sendKeys("text"); no luck, any suggestion now why this happening, it’s not failing anywhere but aslo not writing anything, and forcing me to use Thead.sleep(); which is normally not recommended.

Comment: See my update, If it does't work you can stick with ur thread.sleep.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this for an element to become visible on the screen.

```
new WebDriverWait(10, driver).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("jxxx")).
```

In this case, wait time is a maximum of 10 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but the issue is if the page is still in loading condition, I don’t know how driver finds all the locators. and make the test pass. But actually it does not enter or click any elements. But if i put Thread.sleep it waits and fill and click the elements.

page loads perfectly only I put thread.sleep() 

Comment: I see that you are waiting till the element is present. Checking for the element to be present looks if the element is loaded in the DOM, whether yet visible or not. Waiting for the element to become visible is the right thing to do.